# shortcodes inside shortcode to sum values

Tags: shortcode, array

I have statistical shortcodes that return values

[stat1 val="usa"] 
[stat2 val="europe"]
[stat3 val="china"]
[stat4 val="africa"]

I struggle to create the shortcode that can sum the shortcode values so if

stat1=1 stat2=2 stat2=3 stat2=4
[sumsc][stat1][stat2][stat3][stat4][/sumsc]
it would return the value 10

Comment: Can you edit your question to include your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
add_shortcode('sumsc','sumsc_func');
function sumsc_func( $atts, $content = null ) {
    $sum=0;
    preg_match_all('/stat([0-9]+)/i', $content, $matches);
    if(isset($matches[1])){
        $sum = array_sum($matches[1]);
    }
    return do_shortcode($content)." <div>The sum is <strong>".$sum."</strong></div>";     
}
```

This will add the total sum at the end of the shortcode content.

**Usage example:**

You can try this in your editor:

```
[sumsc][stat1 val="usa"] [stat2 val="europe"] [stat3 val="china"] [stat4 val="africa"][/sumsc]
```

**Edit:** The function above sums the indexes in the shortcode names, not the shortcode values - I think I misunderstood the question ;-)

**Here is an updated version that sums the shortcode values:**

```
add_shortcode('sumsc','sumsc_func');
function sumsc_func( $atts, $content = null ) {
    $sum=0;
    $content=str_replace(array("  ","] [","]["),array(" ","][","]|["),$content);
    $codes=explode("|",$content);
    foreach($codes as $code){
        $sum+=do_shortcode($code);
    }
    return " <div>The sum is <strong>".$sum."</strong></div>";    
}
```

Comment: ok I must have misunderstood him - thanks, I thought he wanted to sum the index in the shortcode names, not the shortcode values ;-)